# Angular service method execution order

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I'm new in Angular and now trying to learn it and have a problem.
I have a simple service method which I call in another component. But I have strange order of execution:

[image]

You can see it in console browser:

[image]

Could anyone please explain how does it work? And how to fix it?

Comment: The order of execution is correct based on the code.   What is happening is the first line starts a http request which runs asynchronously from the rest of the code.  Once the request has been started, the remainder of code runs.  What you should probably do, is return your `this.http.get(..)` line and whenever you call your function subscribe to the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the fact, that I/O operations are usually designed to be non-blocking. Setting up a request via `http.get` is such a non-blocking operation. It takes time to complete and in the meanwhile your other code will run first.

You wouldn't want your app to freeze while it waits for a 5sec response from the server would you?

If you would like to display your result you may just split up your logic for that, like so:

```js
_weatherForecast: WeatherForecast = null;

calculateWeatherForecast() {
  this.http.get<WeatherForecast>(this._url).subscribe((data) => {
      this._weatherForecast = data;
  });
}

getWeatherForecast() {
    return this._weatherForecast;
}
```

That way you may fetch your data independently from displaying them. Angular would detect the change of your variable and render the result. In your template you would just do:

```html
<div>{{getWeatherForecast()}}</div>
```

That has the advantage that you won't fetch new data from the server, every time you want to display your `weatherForecast`. It gives you more control over how often and when to ask your server for new data.

**Edit:**

As it was pointed out in the comments, the code will break, when trying to access a property (in that case `summary`) on `_weatherForecast`. If you would like to avoid that you have two options:

1. Change your template to:

```html
<div>{{ getWeatherForecast()?.summary }}</div>
```

2. Change the logic in your component to:

```
getWeatherForecast() {
    if(this._weatherForecast) {
        return this._weatherForecast.summary;
    }
}
```

You may also change the method `getWeatherForecast()` to `get weatherForecast()`. That way you may access it in your template like a property of your component, like so:

```html
<div>{{ weatherForecast?.summary }}</div>
```

Comment: Hm... interesting. Thanks!
But what if I need to do smth with response or if I have some logic? I always need to perform it inside subscribe method?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. The callback, that you have provided to your `subscribe` method is simply there to "tell" you when your async call has been completed and gives you the opportunity to do something with the resulting data. With a sync call you would do it quite similar. Wait for the data to arrive, then change it, store it, display it, etc... Here it is just a little different in that matter. You cannot apply logic to data that isn't there yet. Also in Angular you would want to "outsource" your code that holds and handles data to a [Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).

Comment: If this code will work? I don't think so. `getWeatherForecast` will return `undefined`

Comment: It will return `null`, but only in the first iteration. Once Angular has detected the change of `_weatherForecast` it will call `getWeatherForecast()` again, which then returns a value.

Comment: but still in browser console at the first time will be errors. Is it good? How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

The code outside the subscribe() method is always executed last. It doesn't matter if it's before or after if it's at the same level.

To fix it instead of doing a "get" method, use a global variable and initialize it on ngOnInit().

```
weather :WeatherForecast = null;

ngOnInit(){
  this.http.get<WeatherForecast>(this._url).subscribe(
    data => {
       this.weather = data;
    }
  )
}
```

I suggest you to organize http calls between component.ts and a service to make it more independent.

Comment: Thanks, but in any case if I need to get some data from http call I need to wait it?

Comment: I've changed as you said, but if any other code executes after subscribe function how can I get data from http call? Even if I move subscribe to ngOnInit the result will be the same

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 portions in your code:**

**Synchronous**

The part outside of your subscribe method is synchronous i.e. it will execute instantly following your program flow of execution.

**Asynchronous**

The part inside your subscribe method is asynchronous i.e. it will only execute when the get request is completed ( response is returned ).

**Explanation**

Now since the http request to the server will take some time. so the synchrouns part will continue its execution and it will not wait for get request to complete.  so the `console.log` [1] will execute first.

The line

`return this.weatherForcast`

is executed next due to synchronous code and return undefined which causes error inside console [2]

Your `subscribe` function is then called at some point later in time (when get request is completed) and data is shown in console [3].